# Tricky partial rational sum

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers, digamma-function

I'm looking for a simplification of 
$$
\sum _{k=r+1}^{2 r} \frac{2 k+2 r+1}{2 k^2-k (2 r+1)+2 r (r+1)}\:.
$$
Mathematica gives a somewhat tautological result in terms of the digamma function $\psi$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \left((6 r+R+3) \left(\psi\left(\frac{1}{4} (6 r-R+3)\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{4} (2 r-R+3)\right)\right)+(6 r-R+3) \left(\psi\left(\frac{1}{4} (2 r+R+3)\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{4} (6 r+R+3)\right)\right)\right)\:,
\end{align*}
$$
where $R=\sqrt{1-12r-12r^2}$. However, on a related sum, Mathematica output a similar answer where the true answer could be written much simpler, so I'm not sure this is the best possible.

Answer (score 1):

Consider first
$$\frac{2k+a}{2(k-b)(k-c)}=\frac 1{2(b-c)}\left(\frac{a+2b}{k-b}- \frac{a+2c}{k-c}\right)$$ where
$$a=2r+1 \qquad b=\frac{1}{4} \left(2r+1\sqrt{-12 r^2-12 r+1}\right)\qquad c=\frac{1}{4} \left(2r+1-\sqrt{-12 r^2-12 r+1}\right)$$ and now
$$\sum _{k=r+1}^{2 r} \frac1{k-b}=H_{2 r-b}-H_{r-b}\qquad \sum _{k=r+1}^{2 r} \frac1{k-c}=H_{2 r-c}-H_{r-c}$$ where appear harmonic numbers.

So
$$\sum _{k=r+1}^{2 r}\frac{2k+a}{2(k-b)(k-c)}=\frac{(a+2 b) \left(H_{2 r-b}-H_{r-b}\right)-(a+2 c) \left(H_{2 r-c}-H_{r-c}\right)}{2 (b-c)}$$

Do you prefer this one ?

**Edit**

Just for your curiosity, using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers, when $r$ is large, the summation is 
$$\frac{1}{6} \left(\sqrt{3} \pi +3\log (3)\right)-\frac{1}{2 r}+\frac{17+2 \sqrt{3}
   \pi }{72 r^2}-\frac{11+2 \sqrt{3} \pi }{72
   r^3}+\frac{133+60 \sqrt{3} \pi }{2160 r^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{r^5}\right)$$ which seems to be quite accurate as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 r & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 5 & 1.369565848 & 1.369605205 \\
 10 & 1.409794490 & 1.409795782 \\
 15 & 1.424507630 & 1.424507803 \\
 20 & 1.432137276 & 1.432137318 \\
 25 & 1.436806524 & 1.436806537 \\
 30 & 1.439958450 & 1.439958456 \\
 35 & 1.442229294 & 1.442229297 \\
 40 & 1.443943198 & 1.443943199 \\
 45 & 1.445282671 & 1.445282672 \\
 50 & 1.446358333 & 1.446358333
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: The issue would be that $b,c$ are complex ($r\ge1$), so harmonic numbers aren't quite the correct notion (as far as terms like $H_{r-b}$ are concerned).

Comment: @RossB. What about the generalized harmonic numbers ?

Comment: I think that would be fine, but I think what you wrote is essentially the digamma version that Mathematica returned.

Comment: @RossB.. I agree but I feel it is nicer and easy to make more general for $a(r)$, $b(r)$, $c(r)$.